# jquery variable substitution

Tags: javascript, jquery, string-concatenation

this works ..

```
$("select[title='First Choice'] option[text='hello']").remove();
```

A number of variations of this does not .. i know this is stupid.

```
var what='hello';

    $("select[title='First Choice'] option[text=$what]").remove();
```

also tried these.

```
$("select[title='First Choice'] option[text=$(what)]").remove();
$("select[title='First Choice'] option[text='$what']").remove();
$("select[title='First Choice'] option[text=$what.val()]").remove();
```

Comment: This is javascript, not php... these types of text substitution don't even apply.  You need to insert into the string manually.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want this:

```
$("select[title='First Choice'] option[text=" + what + "]").remove();
```

Comment: that works great.. but why doesn't this:  $("select[title='Third Choice'] option[value='1']").after($("<option></option>").attr("value","5").text("+ what +"));

Comment: @cyberpine: In that code snippet, you have `what` inside of a string. Just do: `.text(what)`